# How to map children on a phpcr document. Children always empty

Tags: doctrine-odm, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

i have a document 'Page' which should have different "elements" of unstructured content on the page.

The mapping of my document is loaded properly (i can create documents) and it looks like that:

```
<document name="Gondoliere\CoreBundle\Document\Page">

    <nodename name="title" />

    <field name="name" type="string" nullable="true" />

    <parent-document name="parentDocument" />
    <children name="contents" fetch-depth="3" />
</document>
```

I expect the `$home->getContents()` to return a collection with my items.

The node:dump --props looks like that:

```
Home:
- jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
- jcr:mixinTypes = Array(    [0] => phpcr:managed)
- phpcr:class = Gondoliere\CoreBundle\Document\Page
- phpcr:classparents = Array()
- name = Startseite
  687509281:
  - jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
  - jcr:mixinTypes = Array(    [0] => phpcr:managed)
  - phpcr:class = Gondoliere\CoreBundle\Document\SimpleElement
  - phpcr:classparents = Array()
  - headline = Willkommen
  - body = hier kommt mein Text
```

Somehow `$home->getContents()->count()` is always `0`.
What am I doing wrong. Page::getContents method looks like that:

```
public function getContents()
{
    return $this->contents;
}
```

Comment: In your dump, there are no children under the home page. did you store the other pages as children of that homepage?

Comment: there is one child, it has a strange name thought ("687509281").
or am i getting the dump wrong?

The children are not of type page but of different other types.

Comment: ah right, there is the child with the numeric name. that should end up on your Page object in the contents field.

Comment: Yeah, it should (i think). But $home->getContents()->count() === 0. Always. Do you have any idea? $home is my "/Home" node, i triple-checked that.